# C++ 4 players in a array after element 3 reset to 0 with modulus

Tags: c++, arrays

4 players in a array after element 3 reset to 0 with modulus. So if its players 3 turn it will reset to player 1 witch is element 0.

Comment: Questions generally have a `?` in them somewhere.

Comment: I really like, how some people think that SO users are psychic... And seeing by the answers, some really are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
player = (player + 1) % 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're somehow missing your actual question? If you'd like to "loop" some index over 0 to 3 (for 4 players) just do something like this:

```
int currentPlayer = 0;
int numPlayers = 4;

// ...

currentPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % numPlayers;
```